# Which DB record to match OAuth social login?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel, oauth

When we fetch the info from, say facebook I look at what other people do and they store the name and email from fb to dbase, next time when people login to their site, if they fetched the same name and email again, they'll be logged into their web app. But what if I change my name and email in facebook? If i try to login again, then wouldn't it give the new email and name instead of the old one? In which case, this would make the web app register that as a new account instead of logging us into the app using the old account. So if I remember correctly, i think facebook also provides us with the facebook user id so i think this will remain unchanged forever, if so then wouldn't matching fb user id instead of matching name and email the way to go since it would still log you in no matter if you change your name/email on fb, or if you change your name/email in the web app(so the fb name/email and the site's name/email are different).

I apologize if this is a dumb/obvious question, but I've tried looking on google and couldn't find anything on this conundrum. Please enlighten me

Comment: Yes, you should use the FB user id to identify users that log in via Facebook. (Be aware though what the fact that user ids are app-scoped from API v2 means.)

Comment: Thanks, i guess i'll try using id!